# Why use Doctrine instead of CakePHP's standard database ORM?

Tags: cakephp, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I've about to start work on a new web project using CakePHP 2.2, having mostly worked with Zend Framework 1 previously.

On first look, I really like the way CakePHP handles models and the underlying database tables, especially with regard to getting one-to-many and many-to-many relationships setup quickly with the minimum of fuss. It seems, quite frankly, a breath of fresh air compared to how I used to do things in Zend Framework.

However, over the last few years whilst using Zend Framework, I had looked at using Doctrine to provide the model relationships that ZF was rather clumsy at doing. Doctrine looked to me to be very powerful and flexible.

So now I am wondering, before I get too deep into my new CakePHP project, should I still consider using Doctrine with my new choice of framework? What advantages and disadvantages does Doctrine bring to the table (no pun intended!) compared to CakePHP's built-in ORM and database functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CakePHP works best if used as a whole. In your specific case though you can use Doctrine instead of Cake's ORM if you like but you will lose lot of features of cake. For eg. the FormHelper does lot of things "magically" like guessing proper input type for fields etc. using the model's schema, automatically showing error message below appropriate fields in forms when validation fails, etc.

As you commented you don't have much experience with Doctrine either so I would suggest sticking to CakePHP's ORM and look for option only if you find it inadequate for your needs.

Comment: I've now pretty much completed porting an old project from ZF1 to CakePHP (because I don't like the direction ZF2 has gone) and I think your answer pretty much sums up my experience with CakePHP so far. I love its relative simplicity in design and can see that to use Doctrine at this stage would make a lot of CakePHP's "magic" redundant. I'm going to stick with CakePHP's ORM for now and look at Doctrine sometime in the future.

Comment: Things has changed a lot since I originally answered this question. The ORM in CakePHP 3.x has been rewritten and is a huge improvement over the previous versions. It can even be used stand alone https://github.com/cakephp/orm  The reverse is also possible: using another ORM library with CakePHP, but personally I don't see any reason to do so. CakePHP 3.x's ORM is that damn good.

Comment: I recently started work on a new project based on CakePHP 3.2, and I must say, the ORM does look very good!

Answer (score 6):

If you have already worked with Doctrine and CakePHP's ORM, you can decide based on the main reasons to change:

- What will give you more productivity?
- What will give you more maintainability?
- What will give you less learning curve?

Personally, I would choose Doctrine, based on the fact that it is really specific to one problem.

Comment: I havn't actually done any serious work with Doctrine yet and only a small amount with CakePHP's ORM, just enough to get some basic functionality of my project drafted. Personally, from what I have played with so far, I think CakePHP answers all three of your questions, at least from what I have seen so far. However, I have to wonder if some way down the line I'm going to find CakePHP's ORM missing some functionality that is offered by Doctrine.